# Solving this permutation

Tags: probability, permutations, recursive-algorithms

I know this is an extremely noob question, but I need some help. since I am stuck

Prove the formula

$$p(n,r) = \frac{(n + 1 -r) \; (r^2 - 3r + 3) \; (r-2)!}{n!}$$

from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/expected-number-of-shuffles-to-sort-the-cards/21273#21273).

Comment: "$r2-3r+3$"? Not sure what the $r2$ is supposed to mean, there.

Comment: I’m afraid that you’re going to have to provide more explanation of what you want, because I can’t make heads or tails of this. Also, is $(r2-3r+3)$ supposed to be $(r^2-3r+3)$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Yes it is supposed to be (r^2−3r+3)

Comment: @CameronBuie : Please see the link, I have enclosed alongside

Comment: I’ve looked at the link, and I’m afraid that I still have no idea exactly what you’re asking. What is the connection between your question and the other question or its answers?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/21273/33870 just towards the end of the answer, its written :- they are only required to sum up n−r. Actually, there are n−r+1 alternatives. Then we get the total number of permutations that give r unsorted cards, and divide over all the permutations: p(n,r)=(n+1−r)(r^2−3r+3)(r−2)!n! I just cant understand, how he wrote it ?

Comment: Okay; I’ve edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott : I understand, it is much clearer now :)

Comment: Why not ask this on the page itself (the author of the answer was connected to the site 8 minutes ago...)?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $p(n,r)$ is the probability that the first shuffle of the deck of $n$ cards (by the prescribed method) will leave exactly $r$ unsorted cards. In order for this to happen, the first shuffle must put $n_1$ cards in correct order at the top of the deck and $n_2$ cards in correct order at the bottom of the deck, where $n-(n_1+n_2)=r$ is the number of cards left in the middle still to be shuffled.

There are $r!$ possible shuffled arrangements of the unsorted $r$ cards, and they’re all equally likely. However, some of them put the right card at the top of this deck of $r$ cards, which means that it would have been added to the top sorted stack. We don’t want to include those: they don’t leave us with $r$ unsorted cards. If the right card ends up at the top of the $r$ cards, the other $r-1$ cards could still be in any order, so there are $(r-1)!$ such permutations. There are also $(r-1)!$ permutations that put the right card on the bottom of the $r$ cards, where it would have gone into the bottom sorted stack. Thus, so far we have $r!-2(r-1)!$ permutations that leave the whole stack of $r$ cards unsorted.

However, we’ve subtracted too much: we subtracted some permutations twice, because some put the right card on the top **and** the right card on the bottom. Those merely leave the middle $r-2$ cards shuffled, so there are $(r-2)!$ of them. We subtracted them twice, so we have to add them back in to get the correct total number of permutations that leave all $r$ cards unsorted:

$$\begin{align*}
r!-2(r-1)!+(r-2)!&=r(r-1)(r-2)!-2(r-1)(r-2)!+(r-2)!\\
&=\Big(r(r-1)-2(r-1)+1\Big)(r-2)!\\
&=(r^2-3r+3)(r-2)!\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now $n_1$, the number of cards in the top sorted set, could be anywhere from a minimum of $0$ up to a maximum of $n-r$, if all of the sorted cards are at the top. To put it a little differently, the first one of the $r$ unsorted cards can be anywhere from the first card in the deck to the $(n-r+1)$-st card. That’s a total of $n-r+1$ different positions that it can occupy. For each of those possible positions of the $r$ unsorted cards there are $(r^2-3r+3)(r-2)!$ permutations of those cards that leave them unsorted, i.e., that don’t put the right card on either the top or the bottom. There is only one possible permutation of the top $n_1$ and bottom $n_2$ cards that gets them in the right places. Thus, we have a total of $$(n-r+1)(r^2-3r+3)(r-2)!$$ permutations of the whole deck that leave an unsorted section of $r$ cards to be shuffled again.

Finally, there are altogether $n!$ possible permutations of the deck, so the fraction that produce an unsorted batch of exactly $r$ cards is

$$\frac{(n-r+1)(r^2-3r+3)(r-2)!}{n!}\;.$$

Since the permutations are equally likely, that is also the probability of leaving exactly $r$ cards to be sorted.

Comment: M Scott : That explains everything, thanks a lot.